# How to determine the Console Character over which the Mouse Cursor is on?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, console, mouse-cursor

I have trouble converting Mouse screen coordinates into the console 2D buffer when the font size is very small. The only method I have found was is this one:

```
COORD CursorToBuffer()
{
    POINT ptCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&ptCursor);
    ScreenToClient(GetConsoleWindow(), &ptCursor);
    /** Now ptCursor has the Mouse Position relative to the console client area. **/

    COORD dwBufferPosition;
    dwBufferPosition.X = ptCursor.x / dwFontWidth;
    dwBufferPosition.Y = ptCursor.y / dwFontHeight;

    return dwBufferPosition;
}
```

When the font is around 12x16, it is accurate.  But when the font size is under 10x10, it starts to mess up.

Can I make this more accurate, or is there another method I should use?

Comment: Are you using `GetConsoleFontSize()` to get the values of `dwFontWidth`/dwFontHeight`? Note it returns sizes in **logical units**, not in **pixels**, so you will have to convert the screen coordinates from pixels to logical units before calculating the position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better than calculating the mouse position is getting its real value. Using `ReadConsoleInput`

Use `ReadConsoleInput` than you get an `INPUT_RECORD` with a `MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD`. It also contains the mouse position.

[See sample code in the MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events)

Answer (score 1):

I tested this program and seems to work fine for font sizes smaller than 10x10, it worked even without calling `LPtoDP`but I left it in. It calls `GetConsoleFontSize` to get the font size and it prints it to the output so you can inspect the values as you make the font smaller. Hope it helps.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fontInfo;
HANDLE hStdout;
HWND hwnd;
HDC hdc;

COORD CursorToBuffer()
{
    POINT ptCursor;
    GetCursorPos(&ptCursor);
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &ptCursor);
    /** Now ptCursor has the Mouse Position relative to the console client area. **/
    COORD dwFontSize = GetConsoleFontSize(hStdout, fontInfo.nFont);

    POINT dpFontSize = { dwFontSize.X, dwFontSize.Y };
    LPtoDP(hdc, &dpFontSize, 0);
    COORD dwBufferPosition;
    dwBufferPosition.X = ptCursor.x / dpFontSize.x;
    dwBufferPosition.Y = ptCursor.y / dpFontSize.y;

    std::string fontSize = "fontSize: " + std::to_string(dpFontSize.x) + ' ' + std::to_string(dpFontSize.y) + "\n";
    OutputDebugStringA(fontSize.c_str());

    return dwBufferPosition;
}

void writeAt(int x, int y, std::string text)
{
    COORD position = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, position);
    std::cout << text;
}

int main()
{
    hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetCurrentConsoleFont(hStdout, FALSE, &fontInfo);

    while (1) {
        COORD cursor = CursorToBuffer();
        std::string txt = std::to_string(cursor.X) + " " + std::to_string(cursor.Y) + "   \n";
        writeAt(1, 1, txt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but this code behaves the same. Maybe its the windows version that is messing this method?